# String with the same content but comparison always returns false

Tags: string, arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

I have the following code, in which using the WiFi library I perform a scan of the available WiFi networks and want to detect if a specific network is available. I am using ESP32 and Arduino IDE. EEPROM memory handling seems to work, but I don't understand why the comparison always returns zero.

```cpp
SSID = EEPROM.readString(500); // I read from eeprom the string stored in pos 500 
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
delay(100);
Serial.println(logg + "SCAN!");
int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
Serial.println(logg + "SE DETECTARON: " + String(n) + " REDES WIFI!");
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
    Serial.println("'" + WiFi.SSID(i) + "' vs '" + SSID + "' SizeOf: " + String(WiFi.SSID(i).length()) + " - " + String(SSID.length()) + " Comparacion " + String(WiFi.SSID(i) == SSID );
}

delay(10);
```

What I get on the serial monitor is the following:

> 'WRT1900AC 2.4GHz' vs 'WRT1900AC 2.4GHz' SizeOf: 16 - 16 Comparacion 0

The two strings look the same, they are the same size. I already tried replacing comparator "==" with `strcmp` and I get -244.
I also tried using `.c_str` as follows:

```cpp
WiFi.SSID(i).c_str() ==  SSID.c_str()
```

but with the same results. If someone comes up with something I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can't compare c-strings with `==`.

Comment: Is this the actual code you ran? Because it's missing a `)` on `String(WiFi.SSID(i) == SSID );` so there's no way this would have compiled.

Comment: How did you do the `strcmp` comparison?

Answer (score 1):

> The two strings look the same, they are the same size.

Although the `WiFI.SSID()` return a String object, however it does not necessary to be ASCII-encoded. The string encoding is depend on the locale setting of the router, and the reason it looks the same is because the `Serial.print()` cast it into ASCII. This can be proof by the following sketch by using both `Serial.print()` and `Serial.printf()` in ESP32 which shown what is actually received (`Serial.printf()` however does not support Unicode formatting in ESP32 implementation, so it will produce some garbage characters).

```
int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  // Serial.print() will cast the WiFi.SSID() to ASCII
  Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));    
  // this shown what WiFi.SSID() truly return
  Serial.printf(" --- %s\n", WiFi.SSID(i)); 
}
```

This will produce results in show in this picture. As you can see some SSIDs produce the correct results but some shown up as garbage.

[image]

So String comparison operator does do the job correctly when you compare `WiFi.SSID(i) == SSID` and the result indeed is not necessary equal for some SSID, even though it "looks" the same to human.

So how to solve it? If you want to treat them "as the same", ironically, converting String object to char array with `.c_str()` does do the job because it convert each char to an ASCII. I guess you just didn't use the char array comparison [strcmp()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) correctly.

```
 if(strcmp(WiFi.SSID(i).c_str(), SSID.c_str()) == 0) {
   // match
 }
 else {
   // not match
 }
```

If you are saying that this c.str() comparison return -244, then edit your question and do a `Serial.printf()` on both String or better off to loop through the String character by charter and print out the HEX code to see what's going on.

Comment: Nether `Serial.print()` nor `c_str()` does any encoding conversion. `c_str()` just exposes the internal buffer and String class is using `strcmp()` for comparison on those internal buffers anyway. You can see all 16 characters, so it isn't some multi-byte issue either.